# Educational discount at Apple Retail Stores?

Tags: apple-store, price

Is it possible to get educationally-priced hardware by visiting any given physical Apple Store, or is that only achievable online or at college stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get educational discounts at a physical Apple Store -- I have done it, though it has been a while ;-).

They require verification of your status which can generally be done with a student id.

Comment: Also, more than just students get a discount. If you were for local/state/fed government or certain companies that work out deals with Apple, you get a discount as well.

Comment: It's an "educational" and not a "student" discount: faculty and staff get discounts, too ;)

Comment: One guy from UK Apple Store told me that I cannot get an educational discount if I'am not a student in UK but he told me that I can get it online. (I am a EU student....)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the educational discount at an Apple Store. Just make sure to bring your student ID.